# redirect htaccess from non-www to www for subapplication

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2-advanced-app

I have sub application (IPB forum) in my frontend part of yii2-advanced application in web folder. I need to make redirect for this forum in htaccess from non-www to www. 
I have same problem in frontend htaccess and I solve it successfully with next rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I tried this one, and doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} forum 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/forum/$1 [R,L]
```

My link for frontend part:
example.com -> www.example.com

And I need same for subapplication:
example.com/forum -> www.example.com/forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```